# Running multiple programs from the for loop

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing

This program prints out the number of lines of each text file one by one:

```
files = glob.glob('*.txt') # 5 files
for f in files:
  with open(f,'r') as fi:
     lines = fi.read().splitlines()
     print len(lines)
```

How can I write my code so that it runs 5 simultaneous programs and prints number of lines at each program separately?

Comment: You want to do them in separate threads? Or in different processes?

Comment: threads or processes which is faster? I need faster computation.

Comment: @BhargavRao i have corrected it

Comment: Generally speaking, in Python, threading simply doesn't make a program faster at all, even if you're running on a multi-core machine. Use the `multiprocessing` module if you want to have actual parallelization.

Comment: you should probably look at `multiprocessing.queue` and perhaps also look at `multiprocessing.pool`

Comment: @Kevin How can I code for multiprocessing in my case?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Do you have a simple code for multiprocessing it?

Comment: check here http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html

Comment: @Kevin in this case, threading will increase performance because each of these threads will be in I/O wait status. And in general, threading does make your program faster (as in most use cases, as in I/O waiting).

Comment: @beiller I would prefer multiprocessing because in my real problem, computation part is more than the reading part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a multi-threaded version of your program:

```
import threading

# called by each thread
def do_task(f) :
  with open(f,'r') as fi:
     lines = fi.read().splitlines()
     print len(lines)

threads = []
files = glob.glob('*.txt') # 5 files
for f in files:
    t = threading.Thread(target=do_task, args = (f))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads :
    t.join()
```

And for fun here is the multi-process version:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

# called by each thread
def do_task(f, l) :
  with open(f,'r') as fi:
     lines = fi.read().splitlines()
     l.append(lines)

lengths = []
processes = []
files = glob.glob('*.txt') # 5 files
for f in files:
    p = Process(target=do_task, args = (f,lengths,))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()

for p in processes :
    p.join()

for l in lengths:
    print l
```

Comment: im not entirely sure how process distribution works to cores ... however *i think* that in this case you run the risk of running all the processes on the same core ... or one process per core until all cores have a process and then the rest just get stacked or what? assuming it uses some kind of round robin distribution this probably works fine (not that it really matters all that much)